# Scroll too fast on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, scroll

I have a draggable, horizontal layout. Which seems to work fine on desktop, iPad and iPhone with 1 exception ...for some reason when using a touch gesture to scroll/drag content on an iPad/iPad the content moves way too fast!

I've uploaded a temporary page so the issue can be viewed here: moymadethis.com/new

Also a CodePen with more simplistic styling: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdJEva

The strange thing is, the CodePen version seems to drag at a normal speed. But when the exact same code is taken out of CodePen and onto a static HTML page, it drags much quicker. I'm not sure if this is due to the CodePen environment it's in?

Normally when you drag the content below where you've pressed will stay below your figure. On this, it seems to move quicker and get ahead of itself.

Hoping someone can help with this, am I missing something?

The javascript in use is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Get the figures width
    var figure_width = $(".project-index figure").css("width").replace("px", "");

    //Get num figures
    var num_figures = $(".project-index figure").length;

    //Work out how manay figures per row
    var num_row_figures = Math.ceil(num_figures / 2);

    //Get the total width
    var row_width = figure_width * num_row_figures;

    //Set container width to half the total
    $(".project-index").width(row_width);

    x = null;
    y = null;

    $(".project-index div").mousedown(function(e){
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    });

    $(".project-index div").mouseup(function(e){
        if(x == e.clientX && y == e.clientY){
        //alert($(this).next().attr("href"));
        window.location.assign($(this).next().attr("href"));
    }
    x = y = null;
    });

});


// Drag-on content
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#main').dragOn();
});
```

Comment: It actually looks like it's something to do with how the dragOn plug-in works? http://dragon.deparadox.com/